# Python script skipping first part of If statement, even though condition hasn't been met

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I have a Python3 script that I want to check to see if a directory exists and create it if it doesn't exist:

```
import os
import csv

inputs_dir = 'FileInputs'

if not os.path.exists(inputs_dir):
    os.makedirs(inputs_dir)
    print('Directory missing, created it')
else:
    #run rest of my program
```

The script keeps skipping the first part of the if statement and goes right to the stuff under else: even though the 'FilesInput' directory isn't there and it should create it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put `print(os.path.exists(inputs_dir))` above the `if` statement and see what it shows

Comment: That said, `pathlib.Path(input_dirs).mkdirs(exist_ok=True|False)` would let you skip the conditional entirely

Comment: I tried print(os.path.exists(inputs_dir)) above the if statement but it doesn't seem to do anything.  The script just seems to skip the entire first part of the if statement and jumps right to the stuff under else:

It jumps to a section of my code:

```
for filename in os.listdir(inputs_dir):
```
And then complains that it can't find the folder (which is what I'm telling it to create if the folder isn't there).